# flash drive inconsistent with ReadyBoost

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, readyboost

4GB Sandisk flash drive can be used for ReadyBoost on a Win 7 Ultimate 64-bit machine.
However, the same drive gives a "...the drive doesn’t have the performance characteristics " error on a Win 7 Pro 32-bit machine.
USB 2.0 ports on both machines; drive is FAT32.

Any reason it works on one Win7 and not the other???

Comment: Try running the test on another port and try running it few more times. It happened to me that a flash drive will one time pass the benchmark and fail next time without any obvious reason.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ReadyBoost service is running on 32-bit machine. To check press Win + R and type "services.msc". Look for it on the list, start it if it's not or try to restart it if is. Also dont forget to right click on the flash drive and go to properties >
ReadyBoost tab to enable it. Btw if you use your drive just to improve the performance of your machine, you should consider formatting your drive as NTFS instead of FAT32, to get better performance. Hope it helps and good luck!